# getting the keys of a dict based on the values which are a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list1 of values:

```
['A','B','C','D']
```

And I have a dict

```
{1: ['A','F'],2:['B','J'],3:['C','N'],4:['D','X']}
```

I would like to obtain the key for every value in the list:

I tried :

```
[dict1[x] for x in list]
```

However ouputs an error because I am not considering the fact the dict value is a list not a single value. How could I achieve this?

My desired output would be a list with the keys of the list1 values:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
[k for x in lst for k, v in d.items() if x in v]
```

**Example**:

```
lst = ['A','B','C','D']
d = {1: ['A','F'],2:['B','J'],3:['C','N'],4:['D','X']}

print([k for x in lst for k, v in d.items() if x in v])
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can flatten the dictionary and use it as a lookup:

```
data = ['A','B','C','D']
d = {1: ['A','F'],2:['B','J'],3:['C','N'],4:['D','X']}
new_d = {i:a for a, b in d.items() for i in b}
result = [new_d[i] for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```